# When does LINQ build its "ON" condition objects?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have the following 'on' set definition in a LINQ query in my C#, trying to merge up two DataTables.  The problem is in `m` , the Column `InputValue` is a string that may contain a numerical value or an alphanumerical value.  This is bad, because I think `Int32.Parse(string)` may be interrupting my query.  My where clause would be specified such that we'd filter out these cases, but that doesn't matter if the Int32.parse function gets called and blows up my execution.

```
               on 
                // m
                new {
                    FormType    = m.Field<int>("FormType"),
                    ID          = (int)Int32.Parse(m.Field<string>("InputValue"))
                } 
                equals
                // z
                new {
                    FormType    = z.Field<int>("FormType"),
                    ID          = z.Field<int>("ZoneID")
                }
                where ... /* bad Int32.Parse cases would be filtered out.. */
```

Comment: Have you tried running it to see what happens?

Comment: The var I have this query output into just says ("Specific Cast is not Valid.")

Comment: Have you tried creating a [mcve]?

Comment: There `where` is going to execute *after* the join condition. You'll need to move filter the table before you join it

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to structure the query to filter the tables *before* joining.

For example:

```
from l in left where IsValid(l)
join r in right 
on /* Your above join condition */
...
;
```